# How can I add the number "Figure number 1" in a drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, numbering

how can I Add the number of a figure when I draw a graph with `\tikzpicture`?
I try to use `\begin{figure}` but it does not work
thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `caption` is part of the `figure` not part of `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw circle(2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A nice circle made with \texttt{TiKZ}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]